# Fetch column if row exists using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, fetch

I have two tables `photo` and `sale`.

`photo` has two columns `id` and `url`.

`sale` has two columns `photoID` and `status`.

The thing is, a photo(row) in `photo` table doesn't have to have a record in `sale` table so we do not know if a photo is on sale or not.

i.e.

`photo`

```
id | url

1  | http://...

2  | http://...

3  | http://...
```

`sale`

```
photoID | status

1       | 'sold'

3       | 'pending'
```

As you can see, photo having `id 2` doesn't have a record in `sale` table.  What I want to do is to pull all photos from `photo` table, and if there is a record of it in `sale` table I want the `status` info too but in a single query.  How can I achieve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   SELECT p.*, s.status 
     FROM photo p
LEFT JOIN sale s 
       ON p.id = s.photoID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT p.*, s.status 
     FROM photo p
          INNER JOIN sale s 
             ON p.id = s.photoID
   UNION
   SELECT p.*, 'not on sale' AS status
     FROM photo p
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                      SELECT * 
                        FROM sale s
                       WHERE p.id = s.photoID
                     );
```